# In map view, marker is getting loaded but the map is not getting loaded

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a map view in a fragment, which get displayed by clicking on nav bar options. So when i try to open my fragment with map view, i am able to see map markers but not the map. Below is my code.

Fragment Code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    mapView.getMapAsync(this);

    //intiMap(mapView);
    return v;
}

private void intiMap(MapView mapView) {
    try {
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("InitMap",e.getMessage());
    }

}


public boolean googleServiceAvailable() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability =  GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getContext());
    if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable)){
        Dialog dialog =  apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this.getActivity(),isAvailable,0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Cant connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    _googleMap = map;
    _googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    _googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    _googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

    //_googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)));
}
```

Main Activity Code:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    Fragment fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragment = new MapFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if(fragment != null){
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int i = 0; i<fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++){
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
        ft.replace(R.id.context_main,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Below is Map i can see:

[image]

Since the map is loaded i believe that there will not be any key or permission related issue.

Comment: If you check your logcat output I'd bet there is some error that states that the map can't be loaded and you need to add your maps api key to your project, or the sha1 of your keystore to your google project. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: Thanks for response, i checked my logcat and was not able to see any errors. I added the api keys. Just a doubt, will the map load with markers, if the api integration is wrong?

Comment: Oh well, so are you calling all the lifecycle methods? I can only see `mapView.onCreate()`

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but do you have internet connectivity for your emulator?

Comment: Yeah, @Barns52 is right! is the emulator has an internet connection? If not, then GoogleMap will not load.

Comment: It does have internet connection. And i also tried running the same in my mobile and ended with same result.